# AwesomeWM: How best should I have only one active screen?

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

My new daily driver is a Zephyrus G14, upon which I've installed Arch and AwesomeWM.

I'm attempting to have it automatically move all windows and workspaces from my internal laptop display to my external monitor whenever I plug it in... and to properly switch everything back as soon as it's unplugged.

I want one screen at all times, and I have a feeling that's something Awesome can deliver well.

Does anyone with relevant experience have any advice on this?

FYI: I use the git version.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

AwesomeWM doesn't (currently) have an API to manage the screens. This is done in X11/Linux using the `xrandr` tool. It can be scripted in the command line and tools like `arandr` helps you generate those scripts. AwesomeWM only detect the changes to those screens rather than initiate them.

Getting the events themselves are a bit trickier. I am not aware of any DE/WM which does this in a reliable way. Even macOS fails miserably to detect them. There is some useful info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458486/how-to-completely-inhibit-lid-switch-events) and [KDE implementation of the change detection](https://github.com/KDE/kscreen/blob/master/kded/daemon.cpp).

Another solution is polling `xrandr` ever few seconds.